# how to fix Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android

Why am I getting : `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` error here ?

```
public class MovieInterface extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MovieResultsPage> {
    public Activity activity;

    MovieInterface(Activity context) {
        this.activity = context;
    }

    public void handleUpcomingMovies() {

    }

    @Override
    protected MovieResultsPage doInBackground(String... strings) {
        TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("d2e5d02fe295efc00bad8da4dc384edf").getMovies();
        MovieResultsPage upcomingMovies = movies.getUpcoming(null, 1, "IN");
        int totalpages = upcomingMovies.getTotalPages();
        return upcomingMovies;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final MovieResultsPage movieDbs) {
        super.onPostExecute(movieDbs);

                ArrayList<MovieClass> mymovielist = new ArrayList<>();
                for (MovieDb movieResult : movieDbs.getResults()) {
                    mymovielist.add(new MovieClass(movieResult.getTitle(), movieResult.getOverview()));
                }

                MovieAdapter movieClassArrayAdapter = new MovieAdapter(activity, R.layout.movie_list_item, mymovielist);

                ((ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.upcomingMoviesList)).setAdapter(movieClassArrayAdapter);

    }
```

#### Method Call :

```
MovieInterface movieInterface = new MovieInterface(this) ;
movieInterface.execute() ;
```

As other answers for similar questions have suggessted , I am not doing any UI updates inside the background method . But still am getting the error.

I'm new to android and java . How do I fix this ?

Comment: You don't need runOnUiThread in onPostExecute. How to call this asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `looper.prepare()` in the `run()` method of your new thread.

A `Handler` can't dispatch `Messages` or `Runnables` to the `Looper` of a thread if it does not exist. Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#prepare()) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

More details in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui).

Comment: where should I put this line ? please be more specifc.

Comment: Well is there somewhere you are currently doing `new Handler().post()?`

Comment: In `onPostExecute` method

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute() is invoked on the main UI thread. Try removing the runOnUiThread() call. For more details on AsyncTask see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Are you invoking the AsyncTask from the main thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763476/start-async-task-within-a-worker-thread

Answer (score 0):

The culprit may be one of the method calls in your `doInBackground` method.
try running those on UIThread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("d2e5d02fe295efc00bad8da4dc384edf").getMovies();
                MovieResultsPage upcomingMovies = movies.getUpcoming(null, 1, "IN");
                int totalpages = upcomingMovies.getTotalPages();
                return upcomingMovies;
            }
        });
```